# How many workers does gunicorn use by default?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, worker

I can't seem to find the answer in gunicorn documentations. When you run a flask app using gunicorn without specifying the number of workers and threads, what is the default values for them?

Command:

```
gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-processes) documentation for the number of workers:

> By default, the value of the `WEB_CONCURRENCY` environment variable. If it is not defined, the default is `1`.

Comment: Interesting.  [I previously noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62330039/2052575) that Heroku sets this value to `2`.  Seems this is how they do it; exporting this env var results in a change to the default as shown within `gunicorn --help`.