# Python web app in flask runs fine locally, throws NameError on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

When I run the app locally (at localhost:8080), it works as it should. When deployed on heroku, it often gives "NameError: 'APIservice' is not defined".

APIservice is the variable containing the google API object, per Google's documentation. It is build in the 'start' view:

```
@app.route('/start')
def start_teatime(): # Checks auth & builds calendar API (APIservice)
    print('stat_teatime trigger')

    global APIservice

    if 'credentials' not in session:
        return redirect('authorize')

  # Load credentials from the session.
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
        **session['credentials'])

    APIservice = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)


    return redirect(url_for('user_input'))
```

APIservice gets used in the next view ('user_input') and in different functions in the same .py file. Yet, Heroku says APIservice is not defined. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are global variables thread safe in flask? How do I share data between requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask-how-do-i-share-data-between-requests)

Comment: Is there another route that attempts to use `APIservice`, assuming that someone hit `/start` first?

Comment: @Chris I think this is where I am a little out of my debt. My web app uses multiple global variables, which only need to store stuff during a session. The general flow is: users clicks start>user gives some input>script does some processing (using google APIs)>web api notifies user that it's done. 

What would you recommend as a way to handle these global variables? Should I put them all into a Flask session?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith There is one route which always starts with `/start`. `APIservice` is used multiple times along the route, but all after `/start`

Comment: Can you link the google docs which you are trying to follow for this?

Comment: @v25 https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server

Specifically the Complete Example at the bottom. 
They do mention:
`# In a production app, you likely want to save these credentials in a persistent database instead.`
but I don't necessarily want that. My users will use the app once a week, so it's fine for them to log in again at that time.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably seeing this behaviour because Heroku defaults to [two gunicorn workers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62330039/2052575).  This is why global variables are not good for this type of app.  The request that comes in is handled by a random worker, thus your error.

A quick workaround for the problem in your sample code may be to implement a function (at the global level) which returns the `APIService`:

```
def get_api_service(creds):
    
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
        **creds)

    # Save credentials back to session in case access token was refreshed.
    session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

    APIservice = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)
    
    return APIService
```

Then in your route call this like:

```
    # ...    

    # Load credentials from the session.
    if 'credentials' not in session:
        return redirect('authorize')

    APIservice = get_api_service(session['credentials'])

    # Do something with APIservice

    # ...
```

Your other routes would then need to repeat this code, and obtain `APIservice` in the same manner.

The only thing I'm unsure of here is if it's recommended to call what's now in the `get_api_service` function on every request.  The documentation only provides one example `/test` route and not any others, which hints you *would* repeat this in every route that needs to obtain the `APIservice` object.

Comment: Thank you!
I like the idea of having a function which returns the `APIservice` object, that would solve this NameError. I'm afraid the same thing will happen for other global variables though. For example, the script reads all events in the next 7 days and saves their details to global variables: `appointmentTime[]`, `endTime[]`, `location[]`, etc. If I understand it correctly, there global variables won't work with 2 gunicorn workers. 

Would storing these global variables in the Flask session be a good solution? Something like `session['appointmentTime'] = [*list of times*]`?

Comment: Adding comment for anyone how runs into a similar issue: I ended up creating 3 SQL databases with SQLalchemy which now contain all previously global variables. This made my webapp a lot more flexible. It was a bit daunting at first, but I am very glad I went with databases.